# No DataTable results from Microsoft.Data.SqlClient (19249.1) call on Always Encrypted table from a .NetStandard2.0 library. Any suggestions?

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-standard-2.0, sqlclient, .net-core-3.0

I’m trying to do a ‘SELECT * FROM Table’ on a SQL Server table that has three Always Encrypted columns in a .NetStandard 2.0 class library.

I’m getting the following error:  Failed to decrypt column 'Name'. The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlSymmetricKeyCache' threw an exception.    The InnerException is:  System.Runtime.Caching is not supported on this platform.

I've tried the exact same code successfully in a .Net Framework 4.8 console app calling a .Net Framework 4.8 class library,
and a .Net Core 2.2 console app calling a .Net Core 2.2 class library.  Both tests return a datatable with unencrypted data from the Select statement.  Just not in the .NetStandard2.0 test.

```
public static DataTable RunSqlQueryGetDataTable()
{
    var sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT";
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder sb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
    {
    // local db
       IntegratedSecurity = true,
       InitialCatalog = "JL",
       DataSource = "T\\SQLSERVERDEV"
    };

    using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(string.Concat(sb.ConnectionString, ";Column Encryption Setting=enabled")))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlquery, sqlConnection))
        {
           sda.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
           sda.Fill(dt);
        }
    }
    return dt;
}
```

I expect the DataTable to hold the full SELECT * FROM Table unencrypted results which occurs correctly in the .NetFramework4.8 and .NetCore2.2 tests. However, it is choking in .NetStandard2.0.    The Microsoft project documentation on Microsoft.Data.SqlClient https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient says that it supports .NetStandard2.0+

Please help.

Comment: I should add that I'm trying to make the call from a UWP app using the .NetStandard2.0 class library.

Comment: Read the work around on this webpage : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48592556/corrupted-data-using-always-encrypted-in-sql-server?rq=1

Comment: @jdweng  If that is a workaround for asp.net, I'm not sure how to apply that to my situation in the .netstandard2.0 class library.  I actually got it to work in the .netframework4.8.

Comment: Does anyone have another suggestion on how to access an AE table from a .NetStandard2.0 class library?

Comment: I queried the documentation for the API under the **system.runtime.caching** namespace, which states that these APIs should be supported in the .NET framework and the .net core. But the documentation does not say that these APIs support .net standard. But the description of github makes us confused too. So I recommend you could go to the issue of the github library to ask related question.

Comment: Thanks Faywang.  I added this to the issue list on GitHub.  They moved it into the Needs Triage category.